# Send data from client -> server -> processing file -> client on socket.io on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a backend processing file that processes data from MongoDB. When the user clicks a button on the interface, the backend will process data and send that data to front end for visualization processing.

From a few searches, it seems that sockets are the best option for accomplishing this is by sockets. I followed some tutorials and can establish connection between the client and server and handle specific events.

However, since I am starting the server in `app.js`by:

```
var http = require("http");
var http_server = http.createServer(app).listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("listening on port 3000");
});
var http_io = require("socket.io")(http_server);

http_io.on('connection', function(httpsocket){
  console.log("connection established on port 3000");
  httpsocket.on('python-message', function(fromPython){
    httpsocket.broadcast.emit('message', fromPython);
  });
});
```

Then in my `visual.js` file, which is the client side code in the `public` static folder, I have:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
```

I simply want to have a button in `visual.js` that triggers an event so that data in `process.js` (the backend processing file in one of the routes folder) can be sent to visual.js. However, I'm not sure how to get the `httpsocket` global variable from `app.js` to `process.js`. I have tried to `module.export` the `httpsocekt` variable from `app.js`, but node gives me an error that app.js is not a module.

Because I start the server in `app.js`, I would like to keep that server code in `app.js` for structural purposes. How would I accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: Is the problem in exporting the module? If that's the case, can you please attach the code where you are importing/export. Also, if you are using a button to trigger the backend actions, why are you using socket?

Comment: It isn't exactly in exporting the module. I would like to find an alternative way to accomplish what I want to do without exporting the module as it isn't good practice to export app.js (the configuration file). My code for exporting in app.js is `module.export.io = http_io;` which gives me `TypeError: Cannot set property 'io' of undefined`. I am using sockets because I want to transmit data from server to client. The button is simply to send an event to the server the trigger the sending data event.

Comment: Btw why are you using `module.export.io`? Can you replace it with `module.exports = http_io` and give it a try?